# Geting rows in many frames using getView with huge empty spaces in between Android

Tags: android, view, frame

```
   @Override
   public View getView( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View vi=convertView;
       if(convertView==null)
        vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rows_screen, null); 
        TextView tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv.setText(name.get(position));
        tv1.setText(phno.get(position));
        return vi;
   }
```

This is my getview and I am getting result as one row then entire screen as empty. tThen after scrolling two frames another is displayed.

Comment: Please post your layout rows_screen.xml, likely the problem is in there.

Comment: I was waiting for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@drawable/black_background_metal">


     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listviewlayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footerlayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip" >


        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:textColor = "#ffffff">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footerlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <!--    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_show"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Show" > 
        </Button>-->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_save"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Add New Contact" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

   This contains the listview
```

Comment: This contains ListView

Comment: Please this question is still unanswered. If somebody could help.

Answer (score 0):

This is my Activity class:

```java
    package com.example.ems;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.Contacts;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
    import android.view.Display;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        static final int PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST = 0;
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
        MyAdapter ma;
        List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> phno = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            map = db.getAllDataWithName();
            name = (List<String>) map.get("name");
            Log.d("testing", "name in main activity" + name);
            phno = (List<String>) map.get("number");
            Log.d("phone number", "phone number" + phno);

            /*
             * My Adapter class is called
             */
            ma = new MyAdapter(this);
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            lv.setAdapter(ma);

            lv.setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
            // lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

            Button btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);
            // Button btn_show = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_show);

            // Database Handler
            // db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            // showAllData();

            btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            Contacts.CONTENT_URI), PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);

                    /*
                     * EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                     * if(et.getText().toString() != null) { // Inserting Contacts
                     * Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting .."); db.addMyData(new
                     * MyData(et.getText().toString())); Log.d("Message ",
                     * "data added successfully"+et.getText().toString());
                     * 
                     * } else { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                     * "Nothing to save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                     * showAllData();
                     */
                }
            });

            /*
             * btn_show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             * 
             * @Override public void onClick(View arg0) { // Reading all data
             * Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all data.."); List<String> dataList =
             * db.getAllData(); Log.d("data 1 is: ", dataList.get(0));
             * if(dataList.size() > 0 && dataList != null ) {
             * 
             * // Get ListView object from xml final ListView listView = (ListView)
             * findViewById(R.id.listView1);
             * 
             * // Define a new Adapter // First parameter - Context // Second
             * parameter - Layout for the row // Third parameter - ID of the
             * TextView to which the data is written // Forth - the Array of data
             * 
             * ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new
             * ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
             * android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, dataList);
             * 
             * // Assign adapter to ListView listView.setAdapter(adapter);
             * 
             * // ListView Item Click Listener listView.setOnItemClickListener(new
             * OnItemClickListener() {
             * 
             * @Override public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
             * int position, long id) {
             * 
             * // ListView Clicked item index int itemPosition = position;
             * 
             * // ListView Clicked item value String itemValue = (String)
             * listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
             * 
             * // Show Alert Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
             * "Position :"+itemPosition+"  ListItem : " +itemValue ,
             * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();
             * 
             * }
             * 
             * });
             * 
             * } else { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to show",
             * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
             * 
             * } });
             */
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

            switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST):
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        String id = c
                                .getString(c
                                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

                        String hasPhone = c
                                .getString(c
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

                        if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                            Cursor phones = getContentResolver()
                                    .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                            null,
                                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                    + " = " + id, null, null);
                            phones.moveToFirst();
                            String phn_no = phones.getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex("data1"));
                            String name = c
                                    .getString(c
                                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            Toast.makeText(this,
                                    "contact info : " + phn_no + "\n" + name,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            db.addMyData(new MyData(name, phn_no));
                            Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
                            Log.d("message 10", "name" + name);
                            Log.d("message 10", "phn_no" + phn_no);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }// onActivityResult

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public void showAllData() {

            // Reading all data
            Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all data..");
            List<String> dataList = db.getAllData();
            Log.d("data 1 is: ", dataList.get(0));
            if (dataList.size() > 0 && dataList != null) {
                Log.d("Message ", "size of arraylist" + dataList.size());
                // Get ListView object from xml
                final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

                // Define a new Adapter
                // First parameter - Context
                // Second parameter - Layout for the row
                // Third parameter - ID of the TextView to which the data is written
                // Forth - the Array of data

                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                        dataList);

                // Assign adapter to ListView
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                // ListView Item Click Listener
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                        // ListView Clicked item index
                        int itemPosition = position;

                        // ListView Clicked item value
                        String itemValue = (String) listView
                                .getItemAtPosition(position);

                        // Show Alert
                        Toast.makeText(
                                getApplicationContext(),
                                "Position :" + itemPosition + "  ListItem : "
                                        + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                });

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nothing to show",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        /*
         * 
         * 
         * This class is for testing purpose
         */

        class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
            LayoutInflater mInflater;
            Display display;
            TextView tv1, tv;

            // CheckBox cb;
            MyAdapter(Context context) {
                mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name.size());
                mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return name.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View vi = convertView;
                if (convertView == null)
                    vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.rows_screen, null);
                TextView tv = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                tv1 = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                // cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                tv.setText(name.get(position));
                tv1.setText(phno.get(position));
                // cb.setTag(position);
                // cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
                // cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

                return vi;

            }

            public boolean isChecked(int position) {
                return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            }

            public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
                System.out.println("hello...........");
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public void toggle(int position) {
                setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
            }
            /*
             * @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
             * boolean isChecked) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             * 
             * mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked); }
             */
        }

        // MyAdapter class ends here

        /* View holder class */

        // it ends here

    }
```

Comment: This is Activity class

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should **edit** your original question to add additional information.